# for each statement only returns the word 'Array'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a personal advisor page with 3 advisors in my database, I'm trying to create a dropdown box where someone can choose which advisor they'd like. At the moment my dropdown only displays the word 'Array' three times. Here's what I have so far.

```
<select name="advisor">
<?
$sqlQ = "SELECT concat(firstName,' ',lastName) FROM adv WHERE advisor IS NULL";                     
$array=array();
$res = $db->prepare($sqlQ);
$res->execute();

echo("<option>Advisor</option>");

while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  $array[] = $row;
}
foreach($array as $info)
{
  echo("<option>$info</option>");
}
```

Comment: This means that your values are arrays...

Comment: `$row` is an array because of the way you fetched.

Comment: ```$row``` is an associative array. do var_dump($row);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$row` is already an array, so no need to insert your $row into a new array. Just loop the results like this

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  foreach($row as $info)
  {
      echo("<option>$info</option>");
  }
}
```

Comment: why the double loop? Could be useful only if the query stores in the associative array more than one column, which is not the case. In this case you can achieve the same results with better performances with a single while cycle. See the next answer

Comment: @AndreaG I assumed since he was doing a second loop instead of just using the $key names that potentially he wanted the while loop to be universal so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

```
// give the result of concat() an alias so you can easily access it in the result set
$sqlQ = "SELECT concat(firstName,' ',lastName) as name FROM adv WHERE advisor IS NULL";
[...]
while ( $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  // $row is an array, its members correspond with the fields/aliases you've selected
  // apply htmlspecialchars() so that the contents of $row['name'] can't break your html structure
  echo '<option>', htmlspecialchars($row['name']), '</option>';
}
```